# F# operator overloading for conversion of multiple different units of measure

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement, f#-3.0

I want to be able to do this:

```
let duration = 1<hours> + 2<minutes> + 3<seconds>
```

with the following types and functions (and possibly more units of measure):

```
type [<Measure>] seconds     
type [<Measure>] minutes
type [<Measure>] hours

let seconds_per_minute = 60<seconds> / 1<minutes>
let minutes_per_hour = 60<minutes> / 1<hours>

let minutes_to_seconds minutes seconds = minutes * seconds_per_minute + seconds
let hours_to_minutes hours minutes = hours * minutes_per_hour + minutes
```

So basically "hours_to_minutes" should be used for adding hours and minutes, and "minutes_to_seconds" should be used for adding minutes and seconds when I type it in like above.

**Is this possible to do in F#?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually it is possible, there is a way to do this:

```
type [<Measure>] seconds     
type [<Measure>] minutes
type [<Measure>] hours

let seconds_per_minute = 60<seconds> / 1<minutes>
let minutes_per_hour = 60<minutes> / 1<hours>

let minutes_to_seconds minutes seconds = minutes * seconds_per_minute + seconds
let hours_to_minutes hours minutes = hours * minutes_per_hour + minutes

type D1 = D1
type D2 = D2

type Sum = Sum with
  static member inline ($) (Sum, _:^t when ^t: null and ^t: struct) = id
  static member inline ($) (Sum, b)              = fun _  _  a -> a + b
  static member        ($) (Sum, b:int<minutes>) = fun D1 _  a -> hours_to_minutes   a b
  static member        ($) (Sum, b:int<seconds>) = fun D1 D2 a -> minutes_to_seconds a b    

let inline (+) a b :'t = (Sum $ b) D1 D2 a

let duration = 1<hours> + 2<minutes> + 3<seconds>
```

But it's really hacky, I wouldn't recommend it.

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments here are some answers:

- This technique uses overloads which are resolved at compile-time, so there is no performance penalty at run-time. It is based on what I wrote some time ago in [my blog](http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net).
- To add more overloads you will have to add more dummy parameters (`D3`, `D4`, ...) and eventually if you decide to add some overloads which conflicts with an existing one you may have to use a ternary operator `(?<-)` or a function call with explicit static member constraints. [Here's a sample code](https://gist.github.com/gusty/5b6d54b9a94a00599b37).
- I think I wouldn't use it since it requires many hacks (a Dummy overload and 2 dummy types) and the code becomes less readable. Eventually if F# adds more support for inline functions based on overloads I would definitely consider it.
- [Phil Trelford's technique](http://trelford.com/blog/post/Units-of-measure-auto-conversion.aspx) (mentioned in Reed's answer) works at run-time, a 3rd option would be to use phantom types, it may require less hacks.

**Conclusion**

If I had to choose between all alternatives I would use this technique but being more explicit at the call site, I mean I would define conversion functions like `minutes`, `seconds` and that way at the call site I would write:

```
let duration = seconds 1<hours> + seconds 2<minutes> + 3<seconds>
```

And then to define those conversion functions I would use overloads, but it would be less hacky than re-defining an existing binary operator.

**UPDATE 2**

I just found a better solution:

```
type D1 = interface end
type D2 = interface end
type D3 = interface end

type Sum =
    class
        interface D1
        interface D2
        interface D3
    end

type Sum with
  static member inline ($) (_: D1, _: ^t when ^t: null and ^t: struct) = ()
  static member inline ($) (_: D1, b)               = fun a -> a + b
  static member        ($) (_: D2, b: int<minutes>) = fun a -> hours_to_minutes   a b
  static member        ($) (_: D3, b: int<seconds>) = fun a -> minutes_to_seconds a b

let inline (+) a b :'t = (Unchecked.defaultof<Sum> $ b) a
```

which is a bit more scalable, so I would consider using it in production code.

Comment: Wow, this is awesome! I have a few questions though: 
1. Why do you not recommend it? 
2. Do I loose type safety? 
3. If you had to choose, would you rather go with Phil Trelfort's run time solution or this? 
4. What does $ actually do?

Thanks!

Comment: @user3323923, Gustavo is defining an operator `$` by using parentheses `($)`. @Gustavo, I second the question, why would you not use it? It seems like a legitimate solution.

Comment: Well I wouldn't use it because the code is hard to read. But it's important to note that there is no run-time performance penalty, since the overloads are resolved at compile time. More information about this technique in http://nut-cracker.com.ar/

Comment: @Gustavo, I would speculate that the SI module is doing this very thing same thing. Would that be a reasonable assumption?

Comment: Phil Trelford's approach is run-time, this is compile-time. SI module is not doing this, it just define measures, but not overloads.

Comment: +1 from me - this is interesting.  Note that it's still calling the conversion method, though - it's just hiding it by overriding + and getting it to call a new overloaded operator.  This will force all `+` calls (for all types) to route through `Sum` though, won't it?

Comment: Yes, it will re-route to these overloads. The first method is a hack, it will never reach there, the second is the generic case and the rest are the desired overloads. Btw the question didn't mention he wanted not to call the conversion methods.

Comment: Is ($) arbitrary and can I change it to some else, or it it required? The F# reference says that $ is "Used internally for certain compiler-generated variable and function names." Another question: So can I just append more overloads to the last overload in case I want more conversions?

Comment: I switched the accepted answer to this because you proved that it is actually possible and because this answer already has more upvotes than the other.

Comment: Yes it is arbitrary. You can change it to (=>) for example and it will still work. Adding more overloads it's possible but it will be more tricky.

Comment: What exactly would I have to do to add overloads to add milliseconds, microseconds and nanoseconds?

Comment: See the update.

Comment: @Gus Did your blog move to somewhere? I can't seem to open http://nut-cracker.azurewebsites.net/ . Curious to learn about the dummy parameters trick which seems to play a key role in avoiding the "FS0438: Duplicate method" error from the two overloads that only differ in UoM

Comment: @nodakai my blog is gone, but it was also very old so most information there was a bit outdated. In any case, the issue of duplicate methods can be hacked in many ways, see my updated, I just found a better solution that doesn't require adding many arguments.

Comment: @Gus Fantastic. That's easier for me to understand although I gained some understanding on why "duplicate" methods were allowed in the original version after examining IL dumps on sharplab. Here's my attempt to unify two of your sample codes to support all the combinations of hours, minutes and seconds https://sharplab.io/#gist:6ea3d4833e66c9509d32ed8f44c699d1
You should consider publishing a book titled "Writing F# that Don Syme doesn't want to see"

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible directly within F#.  There isn't a way to have the "auto-conversion" succeed directly without specifying the conversion for the types.  You would have to explicitly call your conversion functions (`seconds_per_minute`, etc).

However, Phil Trelford demonstrated a mechanism by which you could [create runtime classes which do support this](http://trelford.com/blog/post/Units-of-measure-auto-conversion.aspx), though with slightly different syntax.  Using his types, you could write:

```
let duration = 1.0 * SI.hours + 2.0 * SI.minutes + 3.0 * SI.seconds
```