# Is it possible to define units of measure for kB, GB, ... with explicit or implicit conversion?

Tags: f#, units-of-measurement

I would like to define a Measure type

```
[<Measure>] type kB
```

that converts to the number of bytes when explicitly cast to an int:

```
(int)7<kB>   // would result 1024kB - explicit would be fine
```

Since there is no way to add an **explicit conversion** operator to a type like in C#, I am stuck. Anyone has an idea? 
Even better would be an **implicit conversion**, so that when a function requires numbers of bytes, it can be called like

```
Allocate(7<kB>) // implicit would be superfine
```

Special conversion functions do not appeal - writing a kB function is trivial but not as nice:

```
let kB(n) = 1024 * n
kB(7)
7 |> kB
```

A conversion function that does the same with units is not cool either

```
7<kB> |> convertToByte
```

Comment: Maybe you fit this option ? https://dotnetfiddle.net/KgaqqL

Comment: I *think* (but I'm not sure) that it's impossible and it seems this question is close in spirit to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21862335/1180426). There's a hack there that might help guide you, but overall there seems to be no feasible approach. Also, [here's a link from the answer](http://trelford.com/blog/post/Units-of-measure-auto-conversion.aspx) with another approach, but it's not without a cost compared to bare units of measure.

Comment: @PatrykĆwiek thx a lot, yes its all said there.

Answer (score 2):

Are active patterns "cool" enough for you?

```
[<Measure>] type kB

// single case active pattern to convert from kB to raw B value
let (|Bytes|) (x : int<kB>) = int(x * 1024)

// use pattern matching in the declaration
// val printBytes : int<kB> -> unit
let printBytes (Bytes(b)) = 
    printfn "It's %d bytes" b

printBytes 7<kB>
// "It's 7168 bytes"
```

Comment: How to make gB and tB also available?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer to your question seems to be no. Which strikes me as add because this conversion is a bit shift. Alas, how about static methods as prescribed from "Programming f# 3.0" page 108?

```
[<Measure>]
type B =
    static member toKB (x: int<B>) =
        1<KB> * x / 1024<B> 

and [<Measure>] KB =
    static member toB (x: int<KB>) =
        x * 1024<B> / 1<KB>

let b1 = 1024<B>
let kb1 = B.toKB b1
```