# F# Units of Measure: Is it available to implicit converting between same type of units?

Tags: f#

Units of same types are: km and m of length, kg and g of weight, is it available to make them calculate without explicit conversion?

And code like this:

```
type [<Measure>]km and [<Measure>]m and [<Measure>]cm
let ``I want`` = 1<km> - 500<m> + 5<cm>
```

Comment: can't be done without explicit conversion

Comment: Here's a way to do something like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21862335/f-operator-overloading-for-conversion-of-multiple-different-units-of-measure